# WPF window's title bar is cramped on Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf

Sorry for all these dumb questions but I'm quite new to WPF so need some guidance!

I have a `RibbonWindow` in my WPF application, but the spacing around and within the title bar is not correct. There is too much space under the title and not enough above so the whole thing looks a bit cramped.

Again, lots of searching on the interweb and no satisfactory explanation or advice. I'm not sure if this is limited to Windows 7 but that's where I'm seeing the problem.

Comment: Could you share a picture please?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unable to provide a screengrab. Is there any styling that can be applied to the titlebar?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the text shown in the screen shot, then no, there is no styling that can be applied to it except typeface (`Font`) adjustments. As you can see from the image, the icon does not line up quite right with the text, but this is normal. You cannot add `Padding` or `Margin` to this text. It is set using the `Window.Title` property.

[image: Example Title]